# Ubuntu 12.04 is changing resolution / refresh rate after login

Tags: 12.04, xorg, resolution, screen

The X11 log below shows a problem: First, the resolution is set to `1920x1080@50p` which is great.

The login dialog seems to be fine at `1920x1080@50p`. After I login, the resolution changes to `1920x1080_60`. The mode `1920x1080_60` is NOT even defined in my `xorg.conf`. I only have ModeLine and Mode defined for `1920x1080@50p`.

I wonder who is setting the other mode `1920x1080_60` ? I already disabled the `nvidia-settings` startup thing. But this didn't change anything.

```
xorg.conf:
```

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 295.40  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-06.nvidia.com)  Thu Apr  5 22:40:54 PDT 2012

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
    Option         "ExactModeTimingsDVI" "TRUE"
    ModeLine       "1920x1080@50p" 148.50 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option         "DynamicTwinView" "0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    #Option         "NoLogo"              "True"
    #Option         "DynamicTwinView"     "False"
    #Option         "NoFlip"              "False"
    #Option         "FlatPanelProperties" "Scaling = Native"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes      "1920x1080@50p"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

#Section "Extensions"
#    Option         "Composite" "Disable"
#EndSection
```

```
Xorg.0.log:
```

```
[    15.707] 
X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
[    15.707] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    15.707] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-26-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    15.707] Current Operating System: Linux server 3.2.0-30-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 24 16:52:48 UTC 2012 x86_64
[    15.707] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-30-generic root=UUID=26612709-c6f0-49dc-8389-527bd572ab4b ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[    15.707] Build Date: 04 August 2012  01:51:23AM
[    15.707] xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    15.707] Current version of pixman: 0.24.4
[    15.707]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    15.707] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    15.712] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Sep 19 23:03:41 2012
[    15.712] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    15.712] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    15.712] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[    15.712] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[    15.712] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[    15.712] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[    15.712] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[    15.712] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[    15.712] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    15.712] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    15.712] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    15.712]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    15.713] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    15.713]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    15.714] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    15.714]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    15.714] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType" does not exist.
[    15.714]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    15.714] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[    15.714] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    15.714] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[    15.714] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[    15.714] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[    15.714] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f6b7167eb00
[    15.714] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    15.714]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    15.714]    X.Org Video Driver: 11.0
[    15.714]    X.Org XInput driver : 16.0
[    15.714]    X.Org Server Extension : 6.0
[    15.715] (--) PCI:*(0:5:0:0) 10de:08a4:106b:00c0 rev 162, Mem @ 0xd2000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00001000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    15.717] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[    15.717] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[    16.170] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[    16.175] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    16.175]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    16.175]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    16.175]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    16.175] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    16.175] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    16.175] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[    16.175] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[    16.175] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[    16.175] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    16.175] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[    16.175] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[    16.175] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[    16.175] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    16.175]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    16.175]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    16.175]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    16.175] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    16.175] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    16.175] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[    16.188] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    16.188]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    16.188]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    16.188] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  295.40  Thu Apr  5 21:57:38 PDT 2012
[    16.188] (II) Loading extension GLX
[    16.188] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[    16.189] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[    16.189] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    16.189]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.13.0
[    16.189]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    16.189]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    16.189] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[    16.189] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[    16.189] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[    16.189] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    16.189]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    16.189]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    16.189] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[    16.189] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    16.189] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[    16.190] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    16.190]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.2.0
[    16.190]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    16.190] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[    16.190] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    16.190] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    16.190] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    16.190]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    16.190]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    16.190] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  295.40  Thu Apr  5 21:38:35 PDT 2012
[    16.190] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    16.190] (++) using VT number 7

[    16.190] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    16.190] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    16.191] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    16.191] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    16.191]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    16.191]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    16.191] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[    16.191] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[    16.191] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    16.191] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    16.191]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    16.191]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    16.191] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    16.191] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    16.191] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    16.191] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    16.191] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    16.191] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    16.191] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    16.191] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    16.191] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    16.191] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    16.191] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "ExactModeTimingsDVI" "TRUE"
[    16.191] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "DynamicTwinView" "0"
[    16.191] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[    16.851] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (PANASONIC-TV (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[    16.851] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[    16.853] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce 320M (C89) at PCI:5:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    16.853] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 262144 kBytes
[    16.853] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 70.89.05.00.00
[    16.853] (--) NVIDIA(0): Interlaced video modes are supported on this GPU
[    16.855] (--) NVIDIA(0): Connected display device(s) on GeForce 320M at PCI:5:0:0
[    16.855] (--) NVIDIA(0):     PANASONIC-TV (DFP-1)
[    16.855] (--) NVIDIA(0): PANASONIC-TV (DFP-1): 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    16.855] (--) NVIDIA(0): PANASONIC-TV (DFP-1): Internal Single Link TMDS
[    16.855] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    16.855] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device PANASONIC-TV (DFP-1) (Using EDID frequencies has
[    16.855] (**) NVIDIA(0):     been enabled on all display devices.)
[    16.879] (II) NVIDIA(0): Assigned Display Device: DFP-1
[    16.879] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated modes:
[    16.879] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "1920x1080@50p"
[    16.879] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1920 x 1080
[    16.917] (WW) NVIDIA(0): PANASONIC-TV (DFP-1)'s EDID does not contain a maximum image
[    16.917] (WW) NVIDIA(0):     size; cannot compute DPI from PANASONIC-TV (DFP-1)'s
[    16.917] (WW) NVIDIA(0):     EDID.
[    16.917] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (75, 75); computed from built-in default
[    16.917] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    16.918] (II) NVIDIA: Using 768.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory access.
[    16.935] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "1920x1080@50p"
[    17.013] (II) Loading extension NV-GLX
[    17.046] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[    17.046] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store disabled
[    17.046] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    17.046] (**) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[    17.046] (II) Loading extension NV-CONTROL
[    17.047] (II) Loading extension XINERAMA
[    17.047] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    17.047] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    17.047] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[    17.047] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    17.047]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.2.0
[    17.047]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    17.047] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    17.047] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[    17.047] (==) RandR enabled
[    17.047] (II) Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[    17.047] (II) Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[    17.047] (II) Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[    17.047] (II) Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[    17.047] (II) Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[    17.047] (II) Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    17.047] (II) Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[    17.047] (II) Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[    17.047] (II) Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[    17.047] (II) Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[    17.047] (II) Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[    17.047] (II) Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[    17.047] (II) Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[    17.047] (II) Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[    17.047] (II) Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[    17.047] (II) Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[    17.049] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    17.069] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[    17.072] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[    17.072] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    17.072] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[    17.072] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    17.072] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    17.072]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 2.7.0
[    17.072]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    17.072]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 16.0
[    17.072] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    17.072] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    17.072] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    17.072] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[    17.072] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    17.072] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    17.072] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    17.072] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2"
[    17.072] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    17.072] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    17.072] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    17.072] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "ch"
[    17.072] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "de_nodeadkeys"
[    17.074] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-F924D37780F51C7D73983061B02A58BFD335116F.xkm
[    17.075] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event3)
[    17.075] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    17.075] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Video Bus'
[    17.075] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    17.075] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[    17.075] (**) evdev: Video Bus: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[    17.075] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Vendor 0 Product 0x6
[    17.075] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Found keys
[    17.075] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Configuring as keyboard
[    17.075] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:31/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input3/event3"
[    17.075] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    17.075] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    17.075] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    17.075] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "ch"
[    17.075] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "de_nodeadkeys"
[    17.075] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[    17.075] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    17.075] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    17.075] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    17.076] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    17.076] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[    17.076] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    17.076] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    17.076] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    17.076] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
[    17.076] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[    17.076] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    17.076] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    17.076] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "ch"
[    17.076] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "de_nodeadkeys"
[    17.076] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    17.076] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    17.076] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Sleep Button'
[    17.076] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    17.076] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[    17.076] (**) evdev: Sleep Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[    17.076] (--) evdev: Sleep Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x3
[    17.076] (--) evdev: Sleep Button: Found keys
[    17.076] (II) evdev: Sleep Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    17.076] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1/event1"
[    17.076] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    17.076] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    17.076] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    17.076] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "ch"
[    17.076] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "de_nodeadkeys"
[    17.077] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Media Center Ed. eHome Infrared Remote Transceiver (0471:0815) (/dev/input/event5)
[    17.077] (**) Media Center Ed. eHome Infrared Remote Transceiver (0471:0815): Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    17.077] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Media Center Ed. eHome Infrared Remote Transceiver (0471:0815)'
[    17.077] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    17.077] (**) Media Center Ed. eHome Infrared Remote Transceiver (0471:0815): always reports core events
[    17.077] (**) evdev: Media Center Ed. eHome Infrared Remote Transceiver (0471:0815): Device: "/dev/input/event5"
[    17.077] (--) evdev: Media Center Ed. eHome Infrared Remote Transceiver (0471:0815): Vendor 0x471 Product 0x815
[    17.077] (--) evdev: Media Center Ed. eHome Infrared Remote Transceiver (0471:0815): Found keys
[    17.077] (II) evdev: Media Center Ed. eHome Infrared Remote Transceiver (0471:0815): Configuring as keyboard
[    17.077] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/rc/rc1/input7/event5"
[    17.077] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Media Center Ed. eHome Infrared Remote Transceiver (0471:0815)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[    17.077] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    17.077] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    17.077] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "ch"
[    17.077] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "de_nodeadkeys"
[    17.078] (II) config/udev: Adding input device IR-receiver inside an USB DVB receiver (/dev/input/event4)
[    17.078] (**) IR-receiver inside an USB DVB receiver: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    17.078] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'IR-receiver inside an USB DVB receiver'
[    17.078] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    17.078] (**) IR-receiver inside an USB DVB receiver: always reports core events
[    17.078] (**) evdev: IR-receiver inside an USB DVB receiver: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[    17.078] (--) evdev: IR-receiver inside an USB DVB receiver: Vendor 0x14f7 Product 0x500
[    17.078] (--) evdev: IR-receiver inside an USB DVB receiver: Found keys
[    17.078] (II) evdev: IR-receiver inside an USB DVB receiver: Configuring as keyboard
[    17.078] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.1/usb2/2-2/rc/rc0/input5/event4"
[    17.078] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "IR-receiver inside an USB DVB receiver" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[    17.078] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    17.078] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    17.078] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "ch"
[    17.078] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "de_nodeadkeys"
[    17.078] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event9)
[    17.078] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    17.078] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    17.079] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event10)
[    17.079] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    17.079] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    17.079] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia Headphone (/dev/input/event11)
[    17.079] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    17.079] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    17.079] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event8)
[    17.079] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    17.079] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    17.081] (II) config/udev: Adding input device MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2) (/dev/input/event6)
[    17.081] (**) MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2): Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    17.081] (**) MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2): Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    17.081] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2)'
[    17.081] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    17.081] (**) MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2): always reports core events
[    17.081] (**) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2): Device: "/dev/input/event6"
[    17.081] (--) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2): Vendor 0 Product 0
[    17.081] (--) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2): Found 3 mouse buttons
[    17.081] (--) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2): Found relative axes
[    17.081] (--) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2): Found x and y relative axes
[    17.081] (--) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2): Found keys
[    17.081] (II) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2): Configuring as mouse
[    17.081] (II) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2): Configuring as keyboard
[    17.081] (**) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2): YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    17.081] (**) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2): EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    17.081] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input6/event6"
[    17.081] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[    17.081] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    17.081] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    17.081] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "ch"
[    17.081] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "de_nodeadkeys"
[    17.081] (II) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2): initialized for relative axes.
[    17.081] (**) MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2): (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    17.081] (**) MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2): (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    17.081] (**) MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2): (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    17.081] (**) MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2): (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    17.082] (II) config/udev: Adding input device MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (technisat-usb2) (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    17.082] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    17.082] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    17.082] (II) config/udev: Adding input device MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb) (/dev/input/event7)
[    17.082] (**) MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb): Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    17.082] (**) MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb): Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    17.082] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb)'
[    17.082] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    17.082] (**) MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb): always reports core events
[    17.082] (**) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb): Device: "/dev/input/event7"
[    17.082] (--) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb): Vendor 0 Product 0
[    17.082] (--) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb): Found 3 mouse buttons
[    17.082] (--) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb): Found relative axes
[    17.082] (--) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb): Found x and y relative axes
[    17.082] (--) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb): Found keys
[    17.082] (II) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb): Configuring as mouse
[    17.082] (II) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb): Configuring as keyboard
[    17.082] (**) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb): YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    17.082] (**) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb): EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    17.082] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input8/event7"
[    17.082] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[    17.082] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    17.082] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    17.082] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "ch"
[    17.082] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "de_nodeadkeys"
[    17.082] (II) evdev: MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb): initialized for relative axes.
[    17.082] (**) MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb): (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    17.082] (**) MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb): (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    17.083] (**) MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb): (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    17.083] (**) MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb): (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    17.083] (II) config/udev: Adding input device MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (mceusb) (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    17.083] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    17.083] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    21.018] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "1920x1080_60"
[    21.255] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-03AF3717FF3AB439A4BAABA686CCB40771CDF520.xkm
```

Comment: i would try updating you driver 295.40 is kinda old. I recommend the 310 driver, also i don't recommend 50hz as a refresh rate. i suggest you perm. switch to 60hz, you won't see a difference, and you might get a few more frames in games.

Answer (score 1):

This is with my experience :

I've installed Ubuntu and other distros on my macbook 6,1 many times and ran into the same issue.

I always have to edit the /etc/default/grub file to account for resolution.

Once you update grub and reboot, the resolution seems to stay where you want it.